# Can I remove this code from blogger contempo template

Tags: templates, blogger

I am implementing my own mobile menu code, so

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isSingleItem'>
    <a class='return_link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>
        <b:include data='{ button: true, iconClass: &quot;back-button rtl-reversible-icon flat-icon-button ripple&quot; }' name='backArrowIcon'/>
    </a>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='{ button: true, iconClass: &quot;hamburger-menu flat-icon-button ripple&quot; }' name='menuIcon'/>
</b:if>
```

Can I remove this code from blogger contempo theme? If I remove this code, any effect on the side of SEO or adsense?